# Cannot access a function member using dot notation swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, syntax, avplayer

I cannot access the playerAv() function's elements outside of the function. How can I access it?

And also I tried to remove the function and use these lines outside of any function and I got an error in the second line. Why I couldn't assign audioLink value outside of a function?

```
var audioLink = "somewebpage.com/abc.pls"
var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: audioLink))
```

I tried

```
let pa = playerAv()
pa.player.volume = currentValue //I got an error here:(
println(currentValue)
```

A part of code:

```
 func playerAv(){
        
        var audioLink = "somewebpage.com/abc.pls"
        var player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: audioLink))
    }
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        var currentValue = Float(sender.value)
        println(currentValue)
        player.volume = currentValue
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Swift isn't JavaScript.

Comment: You need structs or classes if you want to have member variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very confused.

You are mixing up classes and functions.

A function's local variables are not accessible outside the function by design. They only exist inside the scope of the function, and cease to exist as soon as the function returns. Thus your playerAv() function doesn't do anything useful.

It looks to me like you want playerAv to be a class, with instance variables:

```
class PlayerAv
{
  let audioLink: String = "http://somewebpage.com/abc.pls"
  var player: AVPlayer
  init()
  {
    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: self.audioLink))
  }
}
```

Now you can create a PlayerAv object and use it:

```
let pa = playerAv()
pa.player.volume = currentValue
```

Comment: You helped so much. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `var player` inside the function, then this variable's scope is only inside the function.

You need to put the Player creation inside a controller or any class that will suit you:

```
class MyPlayer {

    var player: AVPlayer

    init(link: String) {
        self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: link))
    }

}

let mp = MyPlayer(link: "http://somewebpage.com/abc.pls")
mp.player.volume = 2
```